# nunit UITest xamarin.forms: how to scroll a picker?

Tags: unit-testing, xamarin, nunit, xamarin.forms, ui-testing

I am trying to create UITest for Xamarin.Forms project. Do testing on Android.
I have tryed using some inf available on [Xamarin forum](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/30339/controlling-a-picker-android-numberpicker-ios-uipickerview-from-uitest) but had no luck with it.

Country list for the Picker:

```
List<country> countryList = new List<country>({id="GB", name="United Kingdom"}, {id="US", name="United States"}.... etc);
```

Code for Picker:

```
        var countryPicker  = new Picker();
        countryPicker.SetBinding(Picker.SelectedIndexProperty, "myIndex");
        countryPicker.BindingContext = getCountry;
        countryPicker.BackgroundColor = Color.White;
        countryPicker.AutomationId = "countryPicker";
        countryPicker.SelectedIndexChanged += ((s, e) =>
            {
                    foreach (var element in countryList)
                    {
                        if (element.name.Equals(countryPicker.Items[countryPicker.SelectedIndex]))
                        {
                            getCountry.myCountry = element.id;
                        }
                    }
            });

        //adding all the countries to the list
        foreach (var item in countryList)
        {
            countryPicker.Items.Add(item.name);

        }
```

nunit code:

```
app.Query(c=>c.Marked("countryPicker").Invoke("selectValue", "United States"));
```

Answer: Query for Marked("countryPicker").Invoke("selectValue", "United States") gave 1 results.
But nothing is happening - selection is not done! 
I've tryed to select value to "US" - same, no result.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm pretty sure `AppQuery.Invoke` will try to call a method on the native view (so `UIPickView` or `Spinner`). I'm guessing you would need to change the `Invoke` call according to the platform and use whatever method that platform's picker supports for setting the selection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Open `Xamarin.Form` Picker, Select, & Test result (Android only):

```
// Open up the picker
app.Tap(x => x.Marked("countryPicker"));

// Try to scroll and find the text item only 5 times
for (int i = 0; i< 5; i++)
{
    if (app.Query(m => m.Text("United States")).Length == 0)
        app.ScrollDown(x => x.Id("select_dialog_listview"));
else
    {
        app.Tap(x => x.Text("United States"));
        break;
    }
}
Assert.IsTrue(app.Query("countryPicker")[0].Text == "United States");
```

#### Open `Xamarin.Form` Picker, Select, & Test result (iOS only):

```
/// Open up the picker
app.Tap(x => x.Marked("countryPicker"));

// Assuming a single column picker
var picker = app.Query(x => x.Class(pickerClass).Index(0));
// Try to scroll and find the text item only 5 times
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    if (app.Query(m => m.Text("United States")).Length == 0)
        app.ScrollDown(x => x.Class("UIPickerTableView").Index(0));
    else
    {
        app.Tap(x => x.Text("United States"));
        break;
    }
}
app.Tap(x => x.Class("UIToolbarTextButton"));
Assert.IsTrue(app.Query("countryPicker")[0].Text == "United States");
```

Comment: Thanks for the snippet.  It looks like there is a problem with scroll command. When initiated, i can se how scroll try to perform - started scrolling but bouncing back to start position.  ScrollUp however is working correctly. Could it be nUnit lib problem. I am using 2.6.4.14 version as XamarinUITesting not supporting nUnit 3.0

Comment: What is "pickerClass" variable value?

Answer (score 1):

The following solutions are also now available and won't break when your picker has a value outside of the 5 scroll limit set above. I'm using a NumberPicker in this example but the same approaches should work with a CountryPicker:

```
if (platform == Platform.iOS) {
    app.Query(x => x.Class("UIPickerView").Invoke("selectRow", 3, "inComponent", 0, "animated", true));

    // This is a hack to move the item so that Xamarin Forms will generate the event to update the UI
    var rect = app.Query(x => x.Class("UIPickerTableView").Index(0).Child()).First().Rect;
    app.DragCoordinates(rect.CenterX, rect.CenterY, rect.CenterX, rect.CenterY + 20);

    app.Tap(c => c.Text("Done"));
}
else {
    //NOTE: On Android the values appear to be out by one - setting 4 selects the 3rd value.
    var results = app.Query(c => c.Class("numberPicker").Invoke("setValue", 4));
    var text = app.Query("PickerControl")[0].Text;
    app.Tap(c => c.Text(text));

    //You can also do it like this on Android:
    //    app.ScrollDownTo(m => m.Text("White"), x => x.Id("select_dialog_listview"));
    //    app.Tap(x => x.Text("White"));
    //    Assert.IsTrue(app.Query("PickerControl")[0].Text == "White");
}
```

You can use these solutions after opening the picker.

Of particular note is the small "nudge" on iOS - if you select the picker value using `selectRow` the UI doesn't flag as updated. This hack causes the necessary events to fire and the UI gets updated.

Comment: This works for iOS when you know the _index_ you want to select. But what about selecting the _value_ -e.g. "United Kingdom"? There doesn't seem to be a method available on the underlying UIPickerView.